# What does java binding means for DOM specification?

Tags: dom

Please help me with the concept of language binding regarding the below question

w3c provides java binding and ECMAScript binding for DOM specification . So does this means that for all DOM interfaces defined java has corresponding implemented classes and we can use them? what does language binding concept applies here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's exactly what it means. In Java, the bindings are in the [org.w3c.dom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html) package.

The bindings are essentially translations from the W3C definitions into an actual language. It's a bit like the ancient Roman cookbook [De Re Coquinaria](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/apicius.html): it's a cookbook, but it's in latin, so modern cooks can't actually use it directly. Instead, they need a translation into [dutch](http://www.apiciana.nl/derecoquinaria/inhoud.html) or [english](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/29728/29728-h/29728-h.htm), or whatever language they know.